# shortestpath using relationship filter

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

```
  MATCH PATHS=shortestpath((a:Place{Name:"Mysore"})-
       [r:IS_LOCATED_AT|CARRIES|BELONGS_TO*]-(b:Place{Name:"Bangalore"})) 
  WHERE  ANY ( n IN nodes(PATHS) 
       WHERE
     ("Network" IN labels(n) or n.Name='mplscore.net' AND  n.Name="IP_MPLS_Layer-11")
           OR
      ("Equipment" IN labels(n) or n.Name='Chassis111'))

      RETURN a,r,b
```

when the shortestpath method is called

---

1)
first with mentioned relationship filter  [r:IS_LOCATED_AT|CARRIES|BELONGS_TO*] , it is filering all the paths that has IS_LOCATED_AT,CARRIES,BELONGS_TO.Observed that paths having IS_LOCATED_AT,CARRIES,BELONGS_TO(all these three relationships should be there in path) relationships only considered for filering.

Observed that paths that has the BELOW relationship filter combinations are discarded. We need clarification why they discarded

```
   a)CARRIES,IS_LOCATED_AT
   b)BELONGS_TO,IS_LOCATED_AT
   c)BELONGS_TO,CARRIES
   d)IS_LOCATED_AT
   e)CARRIES
   f)BELONGS_TO
```

2)
among the filtered paths, it is giving shortest path.

Can anybody elaborate why relationship combinations mentioned above not considered for finding shortest path.I would be happy if somebody provides elaboration on this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Potential reason 1: If paths `a` through `f` do not satisfy your `WHERE` clause, then `SHORTESTPATH` will ignore them.

Potential reason 2: The `WHERE` clause has a logical error. This snippet:

```
n.Name='mplscore.net' AND  n.Name="IP_MPLS_Layer-11"
```

will always evaluate to FALSE, since a node's `Name` property cannot have 2 values at the same time. As a result, your `WHERE` clause logically reduces to the following:

```
"Network" IN labels(n) OR "Equipment" IN labels(n) OR n.Name='Chassis111'
```